# Как объединить два списка/кортежа словарей (например списки записей БД) в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, словари, объединение

Имеется два списка словаря:

Первый:

```
x = {'title':'[Лада]', 'prise':'[70000]', 'status':'[Непродана]'},{'title':'[нисан]', 'prise':'[70000]', 'status':'[Непродана]'}
```

Второй:

```
y = {'title':'[Лада]', 'prise':'[70000]', 'status':'[Продана]'},{'title':'[БМВ]', 'prise':'[70000]', 'status':'[Непродана]'}
```

Желаемый результат:

```
 z = {'title':'[Лада]', 'prise':'[70000]', 'status':'[Продана]'},{'title':'[нисан]', 'prise':'[70000]', 'status':'[Непродана]'}, {'title':'[БМВ]', 'prise':'[70000]', 'status':'[Непродана]'}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) замечательно справляется с подобными задачами:

```
import pandas as pd

def merge(*args):
    return (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x if isinstance(x, list) else list(x)) for x in args],
                      ignore_index=True)
              .drop_duplicates('title', keep='last'))

def merge2(*args):
    return (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x if isinstance(x, list) else list(x)) for x in args],
                      ignore_index=True)
              .drop_duplicates('title', keep='last')
              .to_dict('records'))
```

В виде Pandas DataFrame:

```
In [72]: merge(x, y)
Out[72]:
     prise       status    title
1  [70000]  [Непродана]  [нисан]
2  [70000]    [Продана]   [Лада]
3  [70000]  [Непродана]    [БМВ]
```

В виде списка словарей:

```
In [73]: merge2(x, y)
Out[73]:
[{'prise': '[70000]', 'status': '[Непродана]', 'title': '[нисан]'},
 {'prise': '[70000]', 'status': '[Продана]', 'title': '[Лада]'},
 {'prise': '[70000]', 'status': '[Непродана]', 'title': '[БМВ]'}]
```

Comment: Урааа, неужели кто то смог помочь, 3 день бился, гуглил вся и все Спасибо большое!

Comment: Есть ли возможность с вами связаться в личных сообщениях?

Comment: @СергейСмишко, я стараюсь сильно не афишировать свои данные в сети... А что вы хотели?

Comment: Все о том же да по тому же, на данных строчках все работает но если беру  два файла csv к сравнению таки методом то получаю ошибку

Comment: задайте новый вопрос и приведите данные, которые помогут воспроизвести проблему...

Answer (score 1):

```
z = {}
for d in sorted((d for o in (x, y) for d in o), key=lambda d: d['status'] == '[Непродана]'):
    t = d['title']
    if t not in z:
        z[t] = d
z = list(z.values())

print('\n'.join(map(str, z)))
# {'title': '[Лада]', 'prise': '[70000]', 'status': '[Продана]'}
# {'title': '[нисан]', 'prise': '[70000]', 'status': '[Непродана]'}
# {'title': '[БМВ]', 'prise': '[70000]', 'status': '[Непродана]'}
```

Answer (score -2):

Обратите внимание первый это не словарь а список, содержащий словари.

Объединить словари:

```
x = {'title':'[Лада]', 'prise':'[70000]', 'status':'[Непродана]'},{'title':'[нисан]', 'prise':'[70000]', 'status':'[Непродана]'}
y = {'title':'[Лада]', 'prise':'[70000]', 'status':'[Продана]'},{'title':'[БМВ]', 'prise':'[70000]', 'status':'[Непродана]'}

x.update(y)
print "Value : %s" %  x
```

Comment: Это нерабочий код.