# Ошибка при объединении файлов csv c помощью python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

[Ранее заданный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790448/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%91%D0%94-%D0%B2-python)

[Два файла почти одинаковые во втором добавляются только новые строчки либо меняется статус продажи](http://file.sampo.ru/t3r3r9/)

Проблема частично решена, но когда загружаю данные в переменную из csv получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\simplegood\Downloads\weather\monitoring.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\simplegood\Downloads\weather\monitoring.py", line 79, in main
    print(merge(x, y))
  File "C:\Users\simplegood\Downloads\weather\monitoring.py", line 11, in merge
    .drop_duplicates('title', keep='last'))
  File "C:\Users\simplegood\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3535, in drop_duplicates
    duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)
  File "C:\Users\simplegood\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3582, in duplicated
    labels, shape = map(list, zip(*map(f, vals)))
  File "C:\Users\simplegood\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3570, in f
    vals, size_hint=min(len(self), _SIZE_HINT_LIMIT))
  File "C:\Users\simplegood\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 471, in factorize
    labels = table.get_labels(values, uniques, 0, na_sentinel, check_nulls)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1367, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

данные загружаю так:

```
def load(old_projects, path):
    with open(path, "r", newline="") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            old_projects.append({
            'status': row[1],
            'title' : row[0],
            'price' : row[2],
            'a'     : row[3]
            })
        return(old_projects)
```

Comment: Какая информация хранится в предпоследнем столбце? Все данные из CSV читаются как строки - если у вас раньше в ячейках были списки, то лучше использовать другой формат хранения -  CSV для этого плохо подходит...

Answer (score 1):

Данные в DataFrame прочитались, но не уверен, что вы именно этого хотели:

```
In [176]: df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\MegaAuto.csv', sep=',;,', header=None, encoding='cp1251', engine='python')

In [177]: df
Out[177]:
                                        0                      1                             2                                                  3
0            "['Hyundai Santa Fe, 2017']"                     []  "[['1', '899', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/hyundai/santa_fe/...
1         "['Toyota Land Cruiser, 2010']"                     []  "[['1', '849', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/toyota/land_cruis...
2           "['Volkswagen Tiguan, 2015']"    ['b-advItem_upped']  "[['1', '249', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/volkswagen/tiguan...
3                 "['Toyota RAV4, 2011']"                     []       "[['899', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/toyota/rav4/29020...
4   "['Toyota Land Cruiser Prado, 2006']"                     []  "[['1', '199', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/toyota/land_cruis...
5                 "['Lexus RX350, 2008']"                     []       "[['799', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/lexus/rx350/28920...
6         "['Suzuki Grand Vitara, 2011']"                     []       "[['799', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/suzuki/grand_vita...
7       "['Mercedes-Benz G-Class, 2015']"                     []  "[['5', '799', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/mercedes-benz/g-c...
8                  "['Лада Х-рей, 2016']"                     []       "[['549', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/lada/xray/2897844...
9   "['Toyota Land Cruiser Prado, 2014']"                     []  "[['2', '349', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/toyota/land_cruis...
..                                    ...                    ...                           ...                                                ...
26          "['Mitsubishi Pajero, 2013']"   ['b-advItem_pinned']  "[['1', '499', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/mitsubishi/pajero...
27       "['Mitsubishi Outlander, 2013']"  ['b-advItem_removed']  "[['1', '059', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/mitsubishi/outlan...
28               "['Hyundai ix35, 2014']"  ['b-advItem_removed']  "[['1', '019', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/hyundai/ix35/2885...
29                 "['Honda CR-V, 2013']"                     []  "[['1', '159', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/honda/cr-v/287734...
30                "['Toyota RAV4, 2009']"                     []       "[['929', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/toyota/rav4/28773...
31          "['Toyota Highlander, 2011']"  ['b-advItem_removed']  "[['1', '269', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/toyota/highlander...
32  "['Toyota Land Cruiser Prado, 2007']"  ['b-advItem_removed']  "[['1', '249', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/toyota/land_cruis...
33        "['Suzuki Grand Vitara, 2013']"  ['b-advItem_removed']       "[['919', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/suzuki/grand_vita...
34          "['Toyota Highlander, 2011']"  ['b-advItem_removed']  "[['1', '269', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/toyota/highlander...
35              "['Nissan Murano, 2014']"  ['b-advItem_removed']  "[['1', '259', '000', 'q']]"  https://novokuznetsk.drom.ru/nissan/murano/283...

[36 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Читаться то читается и у меня, но вот объединяться 2 таких не хотят(

Comment: очевидно, чтобы протестировать необходим второй файл (data set)... ;-)

Comment: файл точно такой же, лишь меняется одна строчка, я даже 2 одинаковых файла совместить не могу, выдает : not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)